# Accessing smarty multidimensional array values using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I have an array being passed from php which looks like: 
`$resultsArr[123]['A']='q';` 
`$resultsArr[123]['B']='d';` 
`$resultsArr[113]['C']='s';` 
`$resultsArr[113]['A']='ss';` 
`$resultsArr[113]['B']='sd';` 
`$resultsArr[111]['C']='sds';` 
`$resultsArr[111]['A']='vv';` 
`$resultsArr[111]['B']='vv';`

i need to access certain values frmo this array using jquery.

i am trying to access it like 
`keyVal = 123; //dynamically generated` 
var pri = '~$results['keyVal']['B']`'

but i am getting a blank value in variable 'pri'
How can this be solved?

Comment: can you tell us where you have included this code? in your parsed html or your source php file? keep in mind, jquery is client-side and smarty (php) server-side, means jquery doesn't know anything form php-code and analog

Comment: the array part is in php and has been passed on to the html using smarty. the jquery part is in the template itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not convert it to a JSON Array and then use it directly in Javascript, rather than picking out individual elements of the array?

```
<script>

    var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($resultsArr); ?>;

</script>
```

Then use [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to read the array.

This would give you greater flexibility in the long term of what was available to javascript for reading and manipulation.

**EDIT**

You can read a specific element like so, this will `alert` "vv":

```
<script>
    var myVar = myArray[111].A;
    alert(myVar);
</script>
```

Comment: can i convert this to json in jquery?

Comment: Convert it to what? You can use jQuery to iterate over the JSON array and read its values. If you know which elements you want you can do `var myVar = myArray[111].A;` I will do an edit for you in my answer.....

Comment: i am not getting the array in json format from php, is there an equivalent for json_encode in jquery?

Comment: you should be able to JSONify your data in Smarty: `{$results|json_encode}`

Answer (score 0):

**In php use :**

$ResultsArr = json_encode($resultsArr);

$this->jsonResultsArr = $ResultsArr; //its seems u r using smarty.

**In javascript**

jsonResultsArr = "~$jsonResultsArr`";

requireValue = jsonResultsArr[111].A;